# How Do I Convert this specific string to a Datetime in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm really confused I've tried a lot to get it to work.

This is the date I'm trying to convert:

> 6/29/17, 1:15 PM

This is the code:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "MM/dd/yy, HH:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Anyone knows how to approach this?

Comment: looks like `M/d/yy, h:mm tt`

Comment: @Stavm No, `m` for minutes, not months.

Comment: You would really benefit from reading [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) before asking a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `M/dd/yy, h:mm tt` format instead.

- [`M` specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-m-custom-format-specifier-1) is for single digit month numbers without leading zero.
- [`h` specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-h-custom-format-specifier) is for single hour digit 12-hour format without leading zero.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "M/dd/yy, h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: @Brianthaunicorndinosour also consider using `d` rather than `dd` as the latter will fail if the first nine days of the month do not have a leading zero.